# Error (Invalid label -10 at position 0) in GEE

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I am trying to downscale GRACE data by SmileRandomForest Modelling.
Unfortunately, after running the code, I get the following error:

> Image (Error) Invalid label -10 at position 0

Can anyone help me?
Code Link:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/449ad64407df0bd44bb21946aa66b794

Answer (score 0):

I can't run the code because your table isn't shared.  [Just a guess](https://groups.google.com/g/google-earth-engine-developers/c/xPa-ZXm1pSo/m/7D9-YAgmAAAJ), but note that class labels [should be consecutive integers starting at zero](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/classification).

Comment: Dear thanks for your reply, the code link updated. also you can use any table because this error occurs anywhere. Please correct the code if possible. I am not very professional.